# Managing & Adding Groups

Tags: groups, smartgroups

In order to "Manage" or "add" groups I need to know the following:

What are groups? How can they be used?

Comment: Please do some basic reading of the Manual and then come back with some more specific questions.

Comment: It is a general question to get a better feel of what the stack exchange community thinks & can break down into "english" ---

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CiviCRM documentation provides a good rundown of groups and tags (and the best way to utilize each): http://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/4.6/organising-your-data/groups-and-tags/.

One of the great things about Groups is the option to use Smart Groups that automatically add contacts with certain attributes to a specific group, rather than you needing to remember to add each individual one.